# Strip path off of variable in CMake

Tags: cmake

Is there is way I can strip the path off of a variable in my CMakeLists.txt? Say I have a variable

```
RUNTIME_DEPENDENCIES = {
    src/frontend/solve.py
    src/frontend/other.py
}
```

these runtime dependencies are copied over to the bin for the executable to use during execution, but with the way I'm copying them they appear inside their respective folders. So my build folder looks like

```
    build
      | \
     src executable
      |
   frontend
   /       \
other.py  solve.py
```

i'd like the folder to simply contain

```
           build
    /       /         \
executable  other.py  solve.py
```

here's the actualy copy command used:

```
#copy runtime deps
add_custom_target(copy_runtime_dependencies ALL)
foreach(RUNTIME_DEPENDENCY ${RUNTIME_DEPENDENCIES})
    add_custom_command(TARGET copy_runtime_dependencies POST_BUILD
                       COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
                       ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/${RUNTIME_DEPENDENCY}
                       $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${EXECUTABLE_NAME}>/${RUNTIME_DEPENDENCY})
endforeach()
```

I realize I could simply change the 5th line above to

```
${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/frontend/${RUNTIME_DEPENDENCY}
```

but in the case I have multiple dependencies outside of the `src/frontend` I don't want to have to write multiple seperate copy statements in my CMakeLists.txt

Comment: With string operation , probably REPLACE ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The function `get_filename_component` does this:

```
get_filename_component(barename ${RUNTIME_DEPENDENCY} NAME)
```

`barename` is the output variable to hold the filename with path removed.  For example:

```
get_filename_component(barename "src/frontend/solve.py" NAME)
message(STATUS ${barename})
```

would print `solve.py`

Comment: could you give an example of what `barename` would be?

Comment: barename is just a variable.  You could just as easily called it `foo`

Answer (score 1):

As of CMake 3.20, you can use the new [`cmake_path`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.20/command/cmake_path.html#get-filename) command for path manipulation in order to grab the `FILENAME` component of each path:

> ```
> cmake_path(GET <path-var> FILENAME <out-var>)
> ```

For your example, you could do:

```
cmake_path(GET RUNTIME_DEPENDENCY FILENAME MY_FILE_NAME)
```

This command supersedes the `get_filename_component` command.

Answer (score 0):

```
$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${EXECUTABLE_NAME}>/../
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? Dumping code by itself into answer is causing this to get flagged as low quality.